# SVG: text inside text (or using css)

Tags: css, svg, snap.svg

I'm looking for way to position text inside text (see example image).

[image]

Basically as you see on example char 'T' with text inside . The simplest way would be to implement a text mask on rectangle. In my case this won't work since inner text is array of phrases and I need to see them all.

I'm open to any kind of solution. For now I'm trying to do it with SVG + snapsvg library. I'm opened for CSS solutions too.

**UPDATE:**

(in my case wrapping text would be a word or sentence)

Comment: SVG does not have automatic text positioning, you'll need to do this with javascript or a javascript library. Split the text into the lengths you need and position them as required. Too broad since you've provided no details as to what your specific issue is. Alternatively do it in HTML which has text wrapping built in.

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but what if you define a clip-path in a path of the letter and put a whole lot of text inside it?

Comment: @BramVanroy you need to ensure the text wraps appropriately presumably. A clip path would just cut off stuff.

Comment: Are you looking for something that dynamically adjusts font size and line spacing to fit, or more just so it would linewrap correct with a set font size etc ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align:justify` and will be something like this:

```css
div {
  text-align: justify;
  border:1px dashed red;
  margin:auto
}
.w600 {
  width: 600px;

}
.w200 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="w600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam feugiat turpis ut lectus semper sollicitudin. Nullam turpis metus, eleifend ut mattis nec, vehicula a justo. In ac rhoncus urna. Praesent sodales et felis non pretium. Vestibulum eros augue,
  venenatis in cursus at, tincidunt ac sapien. Nullam quis purus luctus ex ullamcorper fringilla vel a odio. Phasellus ligula enim, placerat id tortor nec, maximus maximus tortor. Maecenas accumsan placerat elementum. Maecenas accumsan</div>
<div class="w200">Phasellus vel velit vel mauris facilisis sagittis id eget elit. Nulla sit amet ornare arcu, sed aliquam sem. Sed molestie tempor nibh et pretium. Cras non dui gravida, tincidunt arcu condimentum, dictum dui. Proin iaculis diam lacus, at consequat erat
  lobortis ornare. Donec in ante sed nibh tempus commodo. Vivamus id justo vitae lacus varius imperdiet. Proin porttitor velit enim, ut molestie sem fermentum ut. Integer vitae est non diam dictum sodales. Mauris lobortis lectus a ligula fringilla, semper
  ullamcorper lacus condimentum. Fusce nisl lectus, pharetra sed augue pulvinar, volutpat mollis justo. Phasellus a iaculis turpis, ut placerat magna. Integer et mollis metus, a lacinia arcu. Sed at erat eget lacus dapibus malesuada id eu tortor. Nullam
  et ullamcorper ante, eu venenatis eros. Pellentesque tempor quis risus dignissim vulputate. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam dapibus pharetra risus in consectetur. Sed pretium mollis imperdiet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra,
  per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce eu felis diam. Donec sit amet quam eget lorem posuere porta. Integer porttitor condimentum neque ut volutpat. Nam iaculis feugiat libero et convallis. Nullam sed orci ac ante pellentesque pretium. Donec tincidunt massa
  quis est fringilla, nec porttitor purus varius. Duis id consectetur nunc. Curabitur interdum feugiat lorem a sollicitudin. Duis tempus orci scelerisque elit facilisis tempus. Nulla nec maximus eros.</div>
```

Comment: Char 'T' is quite simple case. I need wrapping text to be a dynamic word or even an sentence.

Comment: Ok so for that I think JS it will be the only solution

Answer (score 0):

The most correct way I could find to do this using only pure CSS is by using `shape-inside` property with polygons or a url to a transparent PNG masks as the value. Currently, however, `shape-outside` seems to be more supported which won't help your specific needs (you could possibly do negative space characters possibly with that approach). This is due to `shape-outside` messing with the overall HTML layout less than shape-inside-- well at least at the chromium project in 2014 (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356778). Checking out caniuse.com shows support for shape-inside shows some support (mostly Chrome, Safari, and Opera-- with some requiring prefixing: http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-inside), but I was unable to get it working in both my Chrome and Chromium installs, current versions, on Windows so it's hard to make a demo-- it seems to have been working back in 2014 as there are a bunch of demos from that timeframe.

In theory you could use the `shape-inside` property with a value of:
`polygon(40.42% 28.25%,42.33% 99.37%,62.17% 99.37%,61.83% 27.50%,99.10% 26.72%,99.63% 0.69%,99.40% 0.41%,61.92% 0.88%,40.83% 1.13%,1.04% 1.47%,1.25% 28.32%); /*a t-shape letter mask-- defined in percentage values*/` and apply it to a block level element selector. If you prefer to work with fixed units the t-shape above could instead be `polygon(161.67px 113.00px,169.33px 397.47px,248.67px 397.47px,247.33px 110.00px,396.42px 106.88px,398.50px 2.76px,397.58px 1.65px,247.67px 3.53px,163.33px 4.53px,4.17px 5.90px,5.00px 113.26px)`

Coming up with the various letter shapes will be very tedious unless you use a tool to draw polygons, such as: http://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/polygon-drawing/ and doing interior regions  of letters like the negative spaces in letters such as A and B may also require using another `shape-inside` or `shape-outside` in tandem. If you wanted to be lazy you could ignore interior whitespace in the letters and it would probably be readable still. You'd need 52 (26 * 2) classes minimum to support upper and lower case letters without any punctuation. I may update this answer will all polygon shapes for letters later depending on my time constraints.